# Network jitter/packet loss/latency measurement tool

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, networking

I'm looking for a tool to use in my network and over the internet to calculate network jitter, packetloss, latency, bandwidth and any other useful metrics.

After some Googling, I can't find anything out there, can someone point me in the right direction?

Server/Client program and Open source would be perfect.

Comment: Have you tried [Iperf3](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php)? Google is aware of it...

Comment: I am just starting the same thing. After a day or more of googling, it seems clear that you should go with iperf https://iperf.fr/i  (there just doesn't seem to be a good alternative; iperf seems to be the industry standard, according to others where I work, and partner companies). There are a lot of tutorials, but I really like this one http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php#iperf-b

Comment: How about https://demo.pathviewcloud.com?

Comment: iPerf is perfect, I use it at work regularly, I didn't know it did UDP though, just raw bandwidth, thanks heaps